# What is minimum and maximum number of red nodes possible in a red black tree with 145 nodes?

Tags: algorithm, red-black-tree

Kindly tell me is there any formula to calculate minimum/ maximum red nodes in a red black tree?

Answer (score 4):

Red Black Trees are binary search trees that are additionally constrained by 4 rules

1. each node is either red or black
2. the root is black
3. every red node must have either 0 or 2 black children
4. every root to null path must have the same number of black nodes

The minimum number of red nodes is simply 0. There is no requirement forcing a Red Black tree to have any red nodes.

We can get the maximum number of red nodes if we interleave red and black nodes on each path and make the number of real red leaves as many as possible. In this case, each red node has two child black nodes, and root node should be black. 
Therefore => n_black = 2 * n_red + 1
We also know that n_black + n_red = n (n being our total number of nodes)

Here are some links if you need further help: http://doctrina.org/maximum-height-of-red-black-tree.html, https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ayg/CS251/slides/chap13b.pdf

Comment: The root is black, no? If it were red, you couldn't have zero red nodes.

Comment: The root is black yes